# Why it is important to first convert code in assembly?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, kernel

While learning reverse engineering, I got to know assembly is best way to see and attack closed source software. Why languages like C/C++ needs to convert code to assembly, why it doesn't directly convert to machine language.

Secondly why it is necessary to map all the code sections (like .stack,.bss) at same location (virtual) every time?

Comment: it is converted to machine language. you are looking at the result of a disassembly on the program memory.

Comment: +1. Oh. that is why assembly varies with dis-assembler.

Comment: assembly language depends on the processor too.. hence assembly code is processor dependent

Comment: You're asking lots of things without giving enough context, explanation, specific examples. Also who says these things are "necessary"?

Comment: @jbat100: I have seen them in /proc data structure of Linux.

Comment: I am afraid, after how many down votes so take away privilege of asking questions?

Comment: You should remove your question and post a new one with some specific sources for the things you describe. You won't loose the right to ask questions.

Comment: Now it is not allowing me to delete post also.

Comment: @pranitkothari don't delete it. its even worse to delete a bad question because it counts more against you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some compilers, just in time compilers for example, do output machine code.  But in general it is much easier to debug a compiler as a human by examining the assembly language rather than machine code.  It is to some extent the "unix way" adding another layer to existing tools, etc.  In this case the assembler and linker need to exist for a target platform, hopefully that is an understood argument.  Then you can simply generate assembly language and debug it visually, and use the existing assembler and linker to turn it into usable machine code.

Answer (score 3):

"assembler" in this case is simply the "human readable form" of machine code. C and C++ compilers generally generate machine-code, but humans have a hard time reading binary code (even when it's presented in a more readable form of Hex or Octal, it tends to be quite hard to "translate").